# Which version of openssl does azure c sdk require?

Tags: openssl, azure-iot-sdk

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
OpenSSL downloaded from github.
Azure IOT C SDK downloaded from github.
Cross compiling for Android NDK version 22.0.7026061
```

Azure iot C sdk is dependent on OpenSSL. I have downloaded and built openssl. However, when building Azure iot sdk, I am getting different errors.

First, I got errors that I am using certain deprecated functions from OpenSSL. I managed to have the errors ignored by adding -Wno-deprecated-declarations to CFLAGS.

Now, I am getting errors in c-utility/adapters/x509_openssl.c about incomplete definition of type "struct ssl_ctx_st."

I am wondering if there is a specific git branch of openssl that I need to build azure iot sdk code against. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment) states the C-SDK has some dependencies and suggest the following commands to install them properly(including the open SSL dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git cmake build-essential curl libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev uuid-devC
```

CMake needs to be at least at 4.4.7 version.

Then try to build with the following commands:

```
cd azure-iot-sdk-c
mkdir cmake
cd cmake
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```